# Input Events from google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

I have a google form that stores results in a google sheet. I am looking for a script that is able to take that data and input it as events into google calender. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Script to Submit Form to Calendar Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831839/google-script-to-submit-form-to-calendar-event)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update Google Calendar from a Google Spreadsheet, the link can help you out:

http://blog.ouseful.info/2010/03/04/maintaining-google-calendars-from-a-google-spreadsheet/

Hope it helps.